# Powershell Task Sequence find current name

Tags: powershell, task, sequence, sccm

lately i've been making a script to find the next available computername in AD. I got it working but when im reinstalling windows on a computer with task sequence it find a new name even tho it allready got a name i want. I tried adding a step in the powershell script:

```
if ($env:computername -like "Computer*")
{
    exit
}
```

This does not work. What is the variable that find the current computername in PE? I use "OSDComputername" to set the computername.

Comment: using `$ENV:COMPUTERNAME` is correct in the way that it will return the current computer name. However, you should check if the change is applied after you set the computer name via `OSDComputerName` (which sounds like a SCCM related variable and not a Windows intrinsic variable). Is the new name reflected in your PoSH session and do you start a new PoSH session or are you reusing the same session? In case the latter is true, then the name will not be updated. What is the content of that `$ENV:COMPUTERNAME` variable when you run your code above)?

Comment: Can't really check what the output of $env:computername is in PE within task sequence since its hard to write any output to a file.

Comment: A better approach for MDT is to combine it with a SQL database : this way a machine can read the current name from the database (based on MAC or serialnumber of the machine).

Comment: if you have a pending reboot due to a changed computername, you could also check the registry at `HKLM:SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName` and use that computername